# At what point does Miller-Rabin become faster than trial division?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms

I've read in various places (and know) that Miller-Rabin is a much faster primality test than trial division for large $N$, but is much slower than trial division for small $N$.

My question is: how large is "large" and how small is "small"?

Comment: When hunting for very large primes, trial division is the first thing to try. It doesn't imply primality, but may show N is composite, saving a lot of time.

Comment: I mean trial division to some small bound.

Comment: Surely this depends heavily on the implementation and on the desired accuracy (i.e., how many iterations of Miller–Rabin you run for the given $N$). I’d guess Miller–Rabin might become faster already for numbers of the order of millions, but any realistic implementation will start with trial division by a handful of small primes anyway.

Comment: Is there a reason you insist to comparing to Miller--Rabin or does it stand for 'some better algorithm'. (AFAIK, in fact in practise other things are used.) 

Comment: @Emil, how many primes in a handful?

Comment: From memory, I think Henri Cohen's book ("A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory") suggests precomputing primes up to 65536 and trial dividing up to there. I hope I am not libelling Cohen here: please treat this comment with the doubt it deserves.

Comment: @Gerry: GMP (https://github.com/AlexeiSheplyakov/gmp.pkg/blob/master/mpz/pprime_p.c) tests primes up to $\log_2N$. The comment in the code suggests that this is not necessarily optimal, but I suppose the rationale is that one iteration of MR takes about $O(\log N)$ arithmetical operations (on numbers of $O(\log N)$ bits), so trial division by primes up to $O(\log N)$ takes still less time. On the other hand, if the input is random, it catches all but a fraction $1/\log\log N$ of composites, and this will not get substantially smaller by increasing the limit.

Comment: Note that they also do not divide $N$ itself by each small prime individually, but take the primes in batches whose product fits into the machine word, compute $N$ modulo this product, and try dividing the remainder by the primes. This reduces the number of operations performed on the full $\log N$-bit integers.

Answer (score 2):

Maple does the following:

1. Check a list of small primes directly
2. Check the gcd with the precomputed number N=2*3*...*97 if gcd is not 1  the number is composite. Otherwise if the number is under $101^2$ it is prime.
3. Repeat step 2 but with N the product of the 3 digit primes. By this stage two "trial divisions have checked all prime factors under 1000 and given a definitive answer for anything under $1018081=1009^2$
4. Go on to fancier methods.

I suppose that having 64 or so more precomputed constants and doing gcd with them could   check all prime factors under 65536 if desired.